# How to upload a java spring boot + mysql + maven project to heroku?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, heroku

I have conflicts to upload my project to heroku, when pushing it shows me this error in the console.

> remote:        [INFO] Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-javac/2.11.1/plexus-compiler-javac-2.11.1.jar (23 kB at 1.3 MB/s)
> remote:        [INFO] Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/thoughtworks/qdox/qdox/2.0.1/qdox-2.0.1.jar (334 kB at 8.6 MB/s)
> remote:        [INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
> remote:        [INFO] Compiling 12 source files to /tmp/build_c0d264c2/target/classes
> remote:        [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
> remote:        [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
> remote:        [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
> remote:        [INFO] Total time:  9.268 s
> remote:        [INFO] Finished at: 2022-11-04T19:11:14Z
> remote:        [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
> remote:        [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1:compile (default-compile) on project ejercicioprueba: Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 11 -> [Help 1]
> remote:        [ERROR]
> remote:        [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
> remote:        [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
> remote:        [ERROR]
> remote:        [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
> remote:        [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
> remote:
> remote:  !     ERROR: Failed to build app with Maven
> remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! If you can't find the issue in application code,
> remote:        please submit a ticket so we can help: https://help.heroku.com/
> remote:
> remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Java app.
> remote:
> remote:  !     Push failed
> remote: Verifying deploy...
> remote:
> remote: !       Push rejected to floating-chamber-10530.
> remote:
> To https://git.heroku.com/floating-chamber-10530.git
> ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
> error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/floating-chamber-10530.git'

I looked for some information about this and I found that in the pom.xml I changed the version of java, I made this change and proceeded to upload my project to heroku and it no longer showed errors in the terminal, but when I accessed the heroku link I did not displays my page shows the message that an error occurred. I am new to developing web applications in spring boot any advice or what could be happening.

Comment: *Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 11*  looks like you are compiling with a jdk <11

Comment: *I did not displays my page shows the message that an error occurred* look into the error files for more informations and share the stacktrace you will find

Answer (score 0):

If you changed Java version try to add system.properties file to the project package and insert this line there: `java.runtime.version=19`. You can change 19 to version you need (from pom file)